# airflow trigger_dag execution_date is the next day, why?

Tags: python, airflow

Recently I have tested airflow so much that have one problem with `execution_date` when running `airflow trigger_dag <my-dag>`.

I have learned that `execution_date` is not what we think at first time from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls):

> Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world,
>   you typically summarize data. So, if I want to summarize data for
>   2016-02-19, I would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight GMT, which would be
>   right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available.

```
start_date = datetime.combine(datetime.today(),
                              datetime.min.time())

args = {
    "owner": "xigua",
    "start_date": start_date
}
dag = DAG(dag_id="hadoopprojects", default_args=args,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))


wait_5m = ops.TimeDeltaSensor(task_id="wait_5m",
                              dag=dag,
                              delta=timedelta(minutes=5))
```

Above codes is the start part of my daily workflow, the first task is a TimeDeltaSensor that waits another 5 minutes before actual work, so this means my dag will be triggered at `2016-09-09T00:05:00`, `2016-09-10T00:05:00`... etc.

In Web UI, I can see something like `scheduled__2016-09-20T00:00:00`, and task is run at `2016-09-21T00:00:00`, which seems reasonable according to `ETL` model.

However someday my dag is not triggered for unknown reason, so I trigger it manually, if I trigger it at `2016-09-20T00:10:00`, then the TimeDeltaSensor will wait until `2016-09-21T00:15:00` before run.

This is not what I want, I want it to run at `2016-09-20T00:15:00` not the next day, I have tried passing `execution_date` through `--conf '{"execution_date": "2016-09-20"}'`, but it doesn't work.

How should I deal with this issue ?

```
$ airflow version
[2016-09-21 17:26:33,654] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
   v1.7.1.3
```

Answer (score 55):

First, I recommend you use constants for `start_date`, because dynamic ones would act unpredictably based on with your airflow pipeline is evaluated by the scheduler.

More information about `start_date` here in an FAQ entry that I wrote and sort all this out:
https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date

Now, about `execution_date` and when it is triggered, this is a common gotcha for people onboarding on Airflow. Airflow sets `execution_date` based on the left bound of the schedule period it is covering, not based on when it fires (which would be the right bound of the period). When running an `schedule='@hourly'` task for instance, a task will fire every hour. The task that fires at 2pm will have an `execution_date` of 1pm because it assumes that you are processing the 1pm to 2pm time window at 2pm. Similarly, if you run a daily job, the run an with `execution_date` of `2016-01-01` would trigger soon after midnight on `2016-01-02`.

This left-bound labelling makes a lot of sense when thinking in terms of ETL and differential loads, but gets confusing when thinking in terms of a simple, cron-like scheduler.

Comment: I don't think it's the `start_date` issue, I haved rounded my `start_date` to the midnight of a day,  my problem is that `execute_date` is set to the next day when dag is triggered externally, for which I think it's unreasonable like I said above.

Comment: I understand the ETL style to schedule, but how can I solve my problem: for unknown reason, my dag is not triggered, how I can triggered it at right `execution_date`, besides `trigger_dag` subcommand, I can think of `backfill`, then if it is this case, why should we need `trigger_dag`, it makes nonsense ?

Comment: Do you have a scheduler running? `airflow scheduler`

Comment: Yes, I have a `LocalExecutor` in my box, and other dags work fine.

Comment: @mistercrunch thanks for your contribution. It would be great if you could clarify that FAQ question further by differentiating between start_time on at the DAG level and start_time at the task level.

Comment: How do I get the fired time ?

Comment: @JiacaiLiu My case is: I thought the dag did not get triggered but it actually did. The task showed as was triggered yesterday but it actually run today.

Answer (score 2):

Airflow will provide the time in UTC. I am not sure at what timezone you are running the tasks. So make sure you think of UTC timezone and schedule or trigger the jobs accordingly.

Try converting the time you want to trigger to UTC time and trigger the DAG. it works. For more information, you can read the below link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls