# Airflow : dag run with execution_date = trigger_date = fixed_schedule

Tags: airflow

in airflow, I would like to run a dag each monday at 8am (the execution_date should be of course "current day monday 8 am"). The relevant parameters to set up for this workflow are :

- `start_date` : "2018-03-19"
- `schedule_interval` : "0 8 * * MON"

I expect to see a dag run every monday at 8am . The first one being run the 19-03-2018 at 8 am with `execution_date` = 2018-03-19-08-00-00 and so on each monday.

However it's not what happens : the dag is not started  on 19/03/18 at 8 am. The real behaviour is explained here for exemple : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620901/1510109 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213964/1510109
The behaviour is  : at each end of the interval ( weekly in my case) the dag is run with execution_date = beginning of the interval (i.e the previous week). This behavour is apparently motivated by an "ETL way of thinking" (see the link above). But it's absolutely not what I want.

How what can I achieve to run my dag each monday at 08:00am with `execution_date`  = `trigger_date` = now ( = current monday 8am) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a [quick look at my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530174/459) with start times and execution_date examples.

You want to run every Monday at 8am.

So this part is going to stay the same:

```
schedule_interval: '0 8 * * MON',
```

You want it to run it's first run on 2018-03-19, since the first run occurs at the end of the first full schedule period after the start date, you should change your start date to:

```
start_date: datetime(2018,03,12),
```

You will have to live with the fact that Airflow will name your DagRuns with the start of each period and pass in macros based on the `execution_date` set to the start of the interval period. Adjust your logic accordingly.

Your first run will start after `2018-03-19T08:00:00.0Z` and the `execution_date`, every other macro that depends on it, and name of the DagRun will be `2018-03-12T08:00:00.0Z`

So long as you understand what to expect from the `execution_date` and you don't try to base your time off of `datetime.now()` your DAGs will be able to be idempotent in operation. Feel free to make a new variable like `my_execution_date = execution_date + datetime.timedelta(7)` within any `PythonOperator` or custom operator (you get execution_date from the context of the task), use template statements like `{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(7)).strftime('%Y%m%d') }}` or `{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7) }}`, or use the `next_execution_date`.

You can even add a dag level `user_defined_macros` like  `{'dt':lambda d: d+datetime.timedelta(days=7)}` to enable `{{ dt(execution_date) }}`. And recently `user_defined_filters` were added like `{'dt':lambda d: d+datetime.timedelta(days=7)}` enabling `{{ execution_date | dt }}`. The `next_ds` and `next_execution_date` would be easier for your purposes.

While thinking about templating, you may as well read up on the built-in stuff out there: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters

Comment: Ok thanks, i will use a custom macro with the relevant date

Answer (score 2):

For me I solved it in this way:

```
{{ ds if dag_run.external_trigger or dag_run.is_backfill else macros.ds_add(ds, 1) }}
```

If DAG was ran by external trigger we shouldn't change `ds`.
If DAG was ran by backfilling we shouldn't change `ds`.
If DAG was scheduled we use macros to increment it by one day.

Answer (score 1):

That is how airflow behaves, it always runs when the duration is completed. Detailed behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856886/airflow-does-not-backfill-latest-run) and [airflow faq](http://airflow.apache.org/faq.html).

But in order to somehow make it run for current week, what we can do is manipulate `execution_date` of DAG. That may be in form of adding 7 days to a `datetime` object (if weekly schedule) or may use `{{ next_execution_date }}` macro.

Agreed that this is only possible if somehow dates are used in your DAG or dependencies are triggered by it.

Just to be clear again, DAG is still running as per its normal behavior. Only thing what we trying to do is manipulate `date` in program/DAG.

```
args = { ....
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018,3,18)
}
dag = DAG(...
    schedule_interval = "@weekly"
)

# DAG would run on 3/25/2018 for week of 18th March

# but lets say we manipulate here 
# {{ next_execution_date }} macro
# or add 7 days 
# So basically we are running with date 3/25/2018 instead of 3/18/2018 for the week of 18th March
```