# Incorrect work of scheduler interval and start time in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can't find the solution with start time of tasks. I have code and can't find where I'm wrong.

When I`ve run DAG, 25.03, 26.03, 27.03. tasks were completed, but today(28.03) tasks not started in 6:48.

I have tried to use cron expressions, pendulum, datetime and result is the same. Local time(UTC+3) and airflow's time(UTC) is different. I've tried to use each time(local, airflow) in 'start date' or 'schedule interval' - no result.

Using: Ubuntu, Airflow v. 1.9.0 and local executor.

```
emailname = Variable.get('test_mail')
l_start_date = datetime(2018, 3, 25, 6, 48) 
l_schedule_interval = '@daily'

WORKFLOW_DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'owner',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': l_start_date,
    'email': emailname,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retries_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

# initialize the DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag_mail',
    default_args=WORKFLOW_DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval=l_schedule_interval,
    start_date=l_start_date,
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of Airflow:

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> Let’s Repeat That: The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

From: https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html

Comment: Thank`s for answer. If you mean that dag starts each midnight, I understand that. How could I set the specific time for each day or each months?

Comment: @НиколайОсиний That is not what he means at all. The run for TODAY the 28th was the one you see that RAN already and is marked the 27th. Check that run's 1st task and see the "start time" for that task.

Cron expressions are simple enough. For a daily task you star out the day of the month, the month of the year, the day of the week. So:
`20 18 * * *` is run daily at 18h 20m UTC. The execution time on the 2018-03-28 will be 2018-03-27T18:20:00Z. The start time will be after 2018-03-28T18:20:00Z depending how long it takes for the scheduler to send it to a worker and the worker to start it.

Answer (score 10):

The [scheduler page](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) does a poor job of explaining that the `execution_date` is set to the start of the period between the previous run and the current run. Why? Well, it's assumed that a monthly, daily, hourly job needs to read all the the data FROM that time UNTIL the current interval time. Yes they could have switched it around.

Examples (Chopping the nano/millis secs to a single digit):

```
DAG start_date DAG schedule_interval Task Started          Task execution_date
2017-12-01     '@daily'              2017-12-02 00:00:02.8 2017-12-01 00:00:00.0
                                     2017-12-03 00:00:01.4 2017-12-02 00:00:00.0

2017-12-01     '@weekly'             2017-12-08 00:00:01.5 2017-12-01 00:00:00.0
                                     2017-12-15 00:00:03.9 2017-12-08 00:00:00.0

2017-12-01     '33 03 * * *'         2017-12-02 03:33:01.6 2017-12-01 03:33:00.0
                                     2017-12-03 03:33:02.2 2017-12-02 03:33:00.0

2017-12-01     '33 03 * * 2'         2017-12-12 03:33:01.7 2017-12-05 03:33:00.0
                                     2017-12-19 03:33:03.1 2017-12-12 03:33:00.0
```

For this last case given note that the start date is not a Tuesday as requested in the interval; because it's confusing that the start time might not align with an interval time, I haven't exactly tested this and recommend that if you wanted to run every Tuesday, your start time should be on a Tuesday like 2017-12-05 or 2017-11-28.

Reference for that 2017-12:

```
#  December 2017
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31
```

So in your DAG's tasks, using the jinja2 templates from the provided context of a run with `{{ds}}` or `{{execution_date}}` will refer to the last column of the examples, as opposed to what `datetime.now()` would tell you regarding the second to last column.

These are provided so that your tasks can be idempotent: f(data) = f(f(data)).

If you run your DAG once, the final state should be the same as if you run your DAG *N* times. That way if you run your (linear) DAG and 3 of 5 tasks succeed, but task 4 failed and task 5 never ran, you can re-run the whole dag, and tasks 1-3 will pre-clean or overwrite data such that the output is not changed from the prior successes of those tasks, and then tasks 4 and 5 can hopefully succeed and you're left in a final good state.