# Understanding Airflow's execution_date and schedule

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

New to airflow coming from cron, trying to understand how the `execution_date` macro gets applied to the scheduling system and when manually triggered.  I've read the faq, and setup a schedule to what I expected would execute with the correct `execution_date` macro filled in.

I would like to run my dag weekly, on Thursday at 10am UTC.  Occasionally I would run it manually.  My understanding was the the dag's start date should be one period behind the actual date I want the dag to start.  So, in order to execute the dag today, on 4/9/2020, with a 4/9/20020 `execution_date` I setup the following defaults:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 4, 2),
    'concurrency': 4,
    'retries': 0
}
```

And the dag is defined as:

```
with DAG('my_dag',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='0 10 * * 4',
        max_active_runs=1,
        concurrency=4,
         ) as dag:

opr_exc = BashOperator(task_id='execute_dag',bash_command='/path/to/script.sh --dt {{ ds_nodash }}')
```

While the dag executed on time today 4/9, it executed with the `ds_nodash` of 20200402 instead of 20200409.  I guess I'm still confused since catchup was turned off, start date was one week prior thus I was expecting 20200409.

Now, I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360077/airflow-dag-run-with-execution-date-trigger-date-fixed-schedule), that basically explains that `execution_date` is at the start of the period, and always one period behind.  So going forward should I be using `next_ds_nodash`?  Wouldn't this create a problem for manually triggered dags, since `execution_date` works as expected when run on-demand.  Or does `next_ds_nodash` translate to `ds_nodash` when manually triggered?

**Question: Is there a happy medium that allows me to correctly get the `execution_date` macro passed over to my weekly run dag when running scheduled AND when manually triggered? What's best practice here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more research and testing, it does indeed appear that `next_ds_nodash` becomes equivalent to `ds_nodash` when manually triggering the dag.

Thus if you are in a similar situation, do the following to correctly schedule your weekly run job (with optional manually triggers)

1. Set the `start_date` one week prior to the date you actually want to start
2. Configure the `schedule_interval` accordingly for when you want to run the job
3. Use the `next` execution date macros for wherever you expect to get the expected current execution date for when the job runs.

This works for me, but I don't have to deal with any catchup/backfill options, so YMMV.